# Are highly skewed dependent variables more susceptible to overfitting?

Tags: regression, distributions, overfitting

I'm developing a linear regression model to predict wildfire sizes. Here the distribution plot for my wildfire data:

[image: wildfire size dist plot]

I determined my model was overfitting by comparing the R2 with my training data to the R2 of my test data.

I have a large sample size and removing features did not resolve the overfitting so I can't figure out what is causing it. I'm wondering if it has to do with the imbalanced distribution of fire sizes.